# How Acumatica Cloud ERP integration works for third party application?

Tags: rest, acumatica

We have an application developed with react and NodeJs and already implemented an MYOB cloud ERP integration to import data. Now we are planning to add a new ERP integration for Acumatica, in the developer document it was mentioned that the rest API is available but I can't find the cloud instance URL, everywhere it was mentioned as localhost only. So can anyone please help me to understand how to connect the Acumatica cloud to fetch details?

Note: I understand the authorization flow like Authorization Code but I'm confused with which URL to use for  and I hope it should be a fixed one as it is a cloud URL

Answer (score 1):

The Integration end points is a rather large topic. I am in the process of writing a blog post on it which is more or less a getting started blog on automating stuff and getting info via ReST. The blog itself is in the context of using these services via PowerShell but if you are able to follow along and get to the point of establishing postman examples of what you need to do you should be able to get to the same end result in any language.
You will want to explore The Web Services Endpoint screen in the integration module as this is where all the Contract Based Soap/ReST definitions are managed. You can even set up custom endpoint if you need.
Do you have access to the Acumatica Portal? The best way to get started is with some of the course work there.
Stand by and ill forward some information for you to get started.
Robert

Comment: Let me know if this helps you. Im going to see if i can also find you a link to other Acuamtiaca resources as well.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/2vwjc823n7c6irs/How%20to%20automate%20a%20process%20in%20Acumatica%20with%20PowerShell%20-%20ADN%20Blog%201.docx?dl=0

Comment: If your able to get into the portal you want to look for Samual Olivers course which walks through working with PostMan on relative to an Acumatica instance.

Comment: This is a link to Acumatica help on the topic. https://help-2020r1.acumatica.com/(W(3))/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=ff22837c-cd3a-410e-b768-88ca6e53b165

Comment: this will also be of use in pointing you in the right direction. https://www.acumatica.com/acumatica-developer-training/web-services/

Answer (score 0):

The URL for the RestAPI is whatever is the site URL of your Acumatica instance. For example if your Acumatica is hosted in [www.ManiMaran.com](http://www.ManiMaran.com). To login to your API :

```
http://ManiMaran.com/entity/auth/login.
```